# Can a python pip package access the database in django?

Tags: python, django, pip, package

Can a python pip package access the database?

Is it possible for a library, installed via pip, can access the entire database of a django project?

If possible, then how so?

And can that library constantly access the database, and upload it on its own server?

Comment: yes, quite possible.

Comment: how exactly????

Comment: Just like any normal python code can access your database with appropriate code. If the library contains malicious code to run database query and the result to remote server, all it needs to have is a simple trigger, which can probably be your own code where you import that library in your project. That  said, it will probably never happen because the code is open for public audit and you can just download the package and view the source code yourself.

Comment: Note that Django is a Python package and is often installed via pip. Most Django projects query a database.